# QFileDialog for directories that have certain content

Tags: qt, qtreeview, qfiledialog

I would like to build a dialog similar to [QFileDialog::getExistingDirectory()](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/qfiledialog.html#getExistingDirectory) for which the OK-button only is enabled when the selected directory contains certain files.

I know I cannot achieve this with [QFileDialog](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/qfiledialog.html), instead I would have to come up with my own QDialog that has a [QTreeView](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/qtreeview.html) coupled to a [QFileSystemModel](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/qfilesystemmodel.html).

1. How can I limit the [QTreeView](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/qtreeview.html) to directories?
2. How can I get the currently selected directory so I can check whether it contains some filenames?

Comment: still working on the implementation, sorry for the delay...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Use [setFilter](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/qfilesystemmodel.html#setFilter) on the QFileSystemModel with either the QDir::AllDirs or QDir::Dirs option, probably the former.
2. connect the [activated(QModelIndex)](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/qabstractitemview.html#activated) signal from the treeview to a custom slot of yours. In this slot pass the QModelIndex to the model's fileInfo/filePath method, to retrieve the info/path for the selected directory, then perform your check

Here is an example:

```
void slotDirectorySelected( const QModelIndex & index )
{
    QFileInfo info = fileSystemModel->fileInfo( index );
    QDir selectedDir = info.dir();
    foreach( const QString entry, selectedDir.entryList() ) {
        // do something with the entry
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that works! I decided to wrap the QFileSystemModel with a subclassed QSotFilterProxyModel to be able to sort and not display any columns beside the name of the directories in the QTreeView